# Unreachable Statement

Tags: android

I am currently creating a meme generator and i get and an error message saying
unreachable Statement what does this mean and how do i solve this problem

Here is the code

```
package com.example.curtis.memegenerator;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class BottomPictureFragment
    extends Fragment {

    private static TextView topMemeText;
    private static TextView bottomMemeText;

    // Variables topmemetext and bottommemetext
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_picture_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
        topMemeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.topMemeText);
        bottomMemeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bottomMemeText);
    }

    //method public void , two parameters
    public void setTopMemeText(String top, String bottom) {
        topMemeText.setText(top);
        bottomMemeText.setText(bottom);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have code after `return view;` comment or remove the code... or move the return statement to the end

Comment: it means `return view;` should be the last statement of that method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reorder onCreateView to look like this;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_picture_fragment,container,false);
    topMemeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.topMemeText);
    bottomMemeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bottomMemeText);
    return view;
}
```

Any code can't be executed after return statement in fuction. Remember then that it should be in last line of function.

Answer (score 1):

You placed code statements after your return statement in onCreateView. They will never be reached.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_picture_fragment,container,false);
    return view; //<- code returns from method here. It will never proceed
    topMemeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.topMemeText);
    bottomMemeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bottomMemeText);
}
```